# Desktop session crashes when resuming from standby

Tags: xorg, suspend, crash, gdm

I'm having this issue since Ubuntu 17.10, now I'm using 18.04.

When I suspend my laptop and leave it sleeping for a few hours, then when I try to resume it the desktop session crashes and the X server is restarted.
Here follows an extract from my syslog file on resuming:

```
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460695] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460697] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460699] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460700] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460703] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460705] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460707] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460708] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460711] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460712] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460715] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460716] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460719] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460720] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460722] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460724] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460727] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460729] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460732] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460733] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460735] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460737] pcieport 0000:04:03.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460738] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460740] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460742] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460744] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460745] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460747] pcieport 0000:04:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460749] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460751] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460753] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.460754] pcieport 0000:04:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.461562] acpi device:41: Cannot transition to power state D3hot for parent in (unknown)
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.467576] pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.477711] acpi PNP0401:00: Already enumerated
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:83
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:84
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:1
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:73
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home acpid: client 2155[0:0] has disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home bluetoothd[1235]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1535316966.7383] bluez5: NAP: removed interface [***]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home bluetoothd[1235]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.480949] acpi PNP0501:00: Still not present
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home upowerd[1707]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.1
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home anacron[17695]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-08-26
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home upowerd[1707]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home anacron[17695]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd-rfkill[17696]: Failed to open device rfkill4: No such device
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home upowerd[1707]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.492529] PM: suspend exit
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd-sleep[17546]: System resumed.
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[2347]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[2347]: message repeated 8 times: [ g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.536839] usb 2-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gsd-color[2021]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Apertura del file «/home/giacof/.local/share/icc/[***].icc» non riuscita: Permesso negato
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:83
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:66
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:71
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:69
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.650558] usb 2-1.5: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.650563] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=817a
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home kernel: [ 4387.650564] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:84
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd-sleep[17546]: /dev/sda:
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd-sleep[17546]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home systemd-sleep[17546]:  APM_level#011= 254
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:72
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home upowerd[1707]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home upowerd[1707]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:68
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:1
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home acpid: client connected from 2155[0:0]
Aug 26 22:56:06 Home acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE) modeset(G0): failed to set mode: No space left on device
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE)
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: Fatal server error:
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE) EnterVT failed for gpu screen 0
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE)
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE)
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]:  for help.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE)
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1535316967.0351] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1535316967.0351] device (eno1): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home kernel: [ 4387.758242] rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home gnome-shell[1960]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2153]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home nautilus[12371]: nautilus: Fatal IO error 11 (Risorsa temporaneamente non disponibile) on X server :1.
Aug 26 22:56:07 Home org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2347]: [2811:2811:0826/225607.057578:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```

I see those errors from Xorg.1.log, but can't figure out how to fix it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing not quite the same issue but a similar one. The crash/hanging issue is intermittent and not a regular one. I have similar kernel logs as you have provided but not the other systemd or upowerd logs. The hanging had become quite regular in 17.10 so I installed 18.04. Have seen the issue few times since then. Don't know how to pin down the issue. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I think the relevant lines are those from Xorg.0.log:

[ 6004.026] (EE) modeset(G0): failed to set mode: No space left on device
[ 6004.026] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 6004.026] (EE) EnterVT failed for gpu screen 0

Not sure whether the issue is with the X server or Nvidia driver though.

Comment: By the way, I opened the following bug meanwhile: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1791981. 
Please click on "This bug affects you"￼, so the status could be updated to confirmed.